# how can I identify network traffic that is blocked?

Tags: firewall, traffic

I have an app that is waiting for a reply from a website but never continues. A browser page connects to the site fine so I think traffic is being blocked by something but I get no indications. I set the firewall to so me if it blocked something. I am running a single cpu VM using windows 12 image

Comment: Windows 12? Are you from the future?

Comment: First off, are you sure it's blocked or is that what you are trying to confirm?
Second, you say your app is waiting for a reply from a website which you can access from a web browser.  What kind of reply are you expecting?  If you could post some more details that would help.

Comment: @EEAA Thought Microsoft want to stay at Windows 10 from now on forever. Such morons ...

Answer (score 1):

If traffic is being blocked, its definitely within the firewall or by the ISP. Depending on the firewall, you should have logs you can look at (or enable logging) that can allow you to see what is filtered and what isn't. If it turns out that isn't it and it's not your ISP, maybe a third party DNS service you have is doing it.